# checking data attribute in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of events on a page. My end goal is to hide a purchase button (by adding a class to it) if the event has passed, using JQuery/Javascript. Each event has a 3 data attributes(month, day, year). I tried using the following method to cycle through an array:

```
   var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".event-event");
   var i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i <  matches.length; i++) {
       var event = matches[i].getElementsByClassName('date');
       var eventDate = event.getAttribute('data-date');
    }
```

But it says that "getAttribute" is not a function, I've also tried ".attr" and it said the same thing.

Comment: Its because you are calling it on an array of objects rather than an object.. checkout something like event[0].getAttribute('data-date');

Comment: Also before calling this method you should check whether event has elements loaded up or not by checking the number of elements in event array

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean when you say "each event has 3 data attributes". You got your `matches` array using document.querySelectorAll(), which means that `matches` is an array of html elements, and html elements don't have month, day, and year attributes. Could you put a bare-bones version of your code on codepen.io or jsfiddle.net? It will be a lot easier to help you if we can see the html that your javascript with working with.

Comment: Inside each div.event-event there is a span with a class of "date". It also has data-month as an attribute on that span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".event-event");
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var event = matches[i].getElementsByClassName('date');
    if (event.length > 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < event.length; j++) {
            var eventDate = event[i].getAttribute('data-date');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".event-event");
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var events = matches[i].getElementsByClassName('date');
    for(var j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
        var eventDate = events[j].getAttribute('data-date');
    }
}
```

`events` is an array that you must iterate through.